# Kentico UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass not working as expected

Tags: c#, api, kentico

I'm attempting to check if a given user has access to a specific Custom Table.
Based on the example listed on the kentico documentation to [check permissions for a custom table](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Checking+permissions+using+the+API), I have setup a similar call, using my custom table class name and userinfo, but the call to "UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass" always return false:

```cs
private bool CheckCustomTableReadPermission(UserInfo user = null)
{
    // Gets the user object
    //UserInfo user = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("CMSEditor");
    //UserInfo user = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("someothervalidusername");
    //UserInfo user = CurrentUser;

    //normally outside of this function
    UserInfo CurrentUser = MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser;
    string CustomTableClassName = "Namespc.TblName";

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = CurrentUser;
    }

    if (user != null)
    {
        // Checks whether the user has the Read permission for the CMS.MenuItem page type
        if (UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass(CustomTableClassName, "Read", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user))
        {
            // Perform an action according to the result
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can anyone also mention what the valid permission name strings are, other than "Read"? (e.g.: "Modify"? "Delete"? "Insert"?)

Does UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass resolve all memberships of the given user, or does it only check if the user is explicitly added to the Custom Table?

Any suggestions? We're using Kentico v8.2.25

Thanks!

Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing it the same way as it's done in

> CMS\CMSModules\CustomTables\Tools\CustomTable_Data_EditItem.aspx.cs

which is:

```
DataClassInfo dci = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(customTableId);
dci.CheckPermissions(PermissionsEnum.Read, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser)
```

And the possible permissions are located in `CMS.DataEngine.PermissionsEnum`. (Read, Modify, Create, Delete, Destroy)

Comment: Thanks, Rocky! That is a better implementation than the path we started going.

We are actually going to get the CustomTable by Class Name, then call CheckPermissions on the custom table object. This is more in line with how we originally wanted (expected) to work with this data.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I'm, dumb.  You're assigning a default value to the user param, not an auto-assigned value.  I would still check to make sure you're getting the user info you're expecting, because that seems to be the most likely cause for the problem.

<strike>You seem to be running into a problem here:</strike>

```
private bool CheckCustomTableReadPermission(UserInfo user = null)
```

Since you're auto-assigning your `user` parameter to null when your method is called, the following statement will always be true:

```
if (user == null)
{
    user = CurrentUser;
}
```

And you will never reach your other statement:

```
if (user != null)
{
    // Checks whether the user has the Read permission for the CMS.MenuItem page type
    if (UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass(CustomTableClassName, "Read", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user))
    {
        // Perform an action according to the result
        return true;
    }
}
```

So your method will always return false.

The IsAuthorizedPerClass() function checks only the user's permissions for the class that you provide to check against and only the specific permission you provide for it to check (e.g. "Read").  So yes, it's only going to see if the user has the Read permission for your custom table.

I'm not 100% certain what all the permissions are, although it appears to be stored in an enum.  I'll get back to you on that one in a bit.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Jerreck, I have also tried to just hardcode the string for the username and confirmed I'm getting the correct userinfo and checked while debugging that I'm getting a valid userinfo.
Seems like the UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass is not evaluating permissions properly. For example, I'm checking using my username (which should have access as a global administrator), but the UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass evaluates to false. Note that the user object itself doesn't have permission explicitly, but via roles -- that would be the case for all the other users in our system (non admin)

Comment: Hm, have you tried checking against a user with the correct roles that has read permissions to the table instead of one with global admin rights?  That may actually be the issue - I've never tested with a global admin user.  That method should be iterating over the roles associated with a user and checking the roles' permissions.  Sorry if that wasn't clear from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `IsAuthorizedPerClass()` method will return true only if the user's role has been granted permission *explicitly* within the role's Permissions for that class. All other times, it will return false even if the user is in fact able to Read/Modify/etc. the custom table.

To get the correct permission strings, you can use `CMS.DataEngine.PermissionsEnum.<type>.ToString()`

To check whether a user has permissions to Read a specific custom table, you will need to make the following 3 checks in order:

```
UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerUIElement("CMS.CustomTables","CustomTables",SiteContext.CurrentSiteName,user)
UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerResource("CMS.CustomTables", PermissionsEnum.Read.ToString(), SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user)
UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass(CustomTableClassName, PermissionsEnum.Read.ToString(), SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user)
```

Comment: Seems like I need to "OR" the last 2 calls, to ensure a given user has access to the custom table. If I call them in sequence, then it will fail, as the last check is to see if the user/role has been explicitly set on the table. It seems to me like the IsAuthorizedPerClass method is malfunctioning, and should actually do this evaluation:



UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerResource("CMS.CustomTables", PermissionsEnum.Read.ToString(), SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user)
UserInfoProvider.IsAuthorizedPerClass(CustomTableClassName, PermissionsEnum.Read.ToString(), SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, user)